# Database can't connect with spring boot

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot

I tried to build RestFull webservice with db connection. But this seems to not connecting with the database. And I get this error in my console.

```
   com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

    The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:174) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.18.jar:8.0.18]
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:64) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.18.jar:8.0.18]
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:836) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.18.jar:8.0.18]



The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_162]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_162]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_162]


Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: db_example
    at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_162]
    at java.net.InetAddress$2.lookupAllHostAddr(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_162]

Caused by: org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:275) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.6.Final.jar:5.4.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:237) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.6.Final.jar:5.4.6.Final]

Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Access to DialectResolutionInfo cannot be null when 'hibernate.dialect' not set
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.dialect.internal.DialectFactoryImpl.determineDialect(DialectFactoryImpl.java:100) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.6.Final.jar:5.4.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.dialect.internal.DialectFactoryImpl.buildDialect(DialectFactoryImpl.java:54) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.6.Final.jar:5.4.6.Final]
```

This is my application.property file

```
server.port=8092

#spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://db_example:3306/db_example
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=


#spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
spring.jpa.show-sql=false
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
```

I can't figure out what is the wrong with this.

Comment: `UnknownHostException: db_example` - you don't have a database server running with hostname 'db_example'. Use the actual hostname of the machine on which the database is running instead of 'db_example'

Answer (score 0):

```
    spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db_example
    spring.datasource.username = root
    spring.datasource.password = root
    spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect =org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect

hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialectMySQL5Dialect
hibernate.show_sql=true
hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=create
hibernate.ddl-auto=validate

hibernate.connection.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/axa_india?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8&zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull
hibernate.connection.username=root
hibernate.connection.password=root
```

Comment: Thank you! But this resolved only one error. I can't figure out other errors

Comment: Hope this will help

Comment: Can you suggest me what are the cause for other errors

Comment: you need add driver for db connectivity, like hibernate and spring

Comment: did you mean this?

Comment: spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.postgresql.Driver

Answer (score 0):

I think the host name is something wrong here.So Kindly check once the host machine name like localhost (or) your proper DB hosted place name.

Because it is showing Exception like unknownHostException.

Answer (score 0):

its duplicate ticket , check with: [https:/stackoverflow.com/questions/2983248/com-mysql-jdbc-exceptions-jdbc4-communicationsexception-communications-link-fai](https:////stackoverflow.com/questions/2983248/com-mysql-jdbc-exceptions-jdbc4-communicationsexception-communications-link-fai)